# Why does loading a block of memory from a DLL only crash at the second call to memmove?

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, segmentation-fault

This is the class in question (only functions that pertain to this question) and everything it depends on (all written myself). It provides an interface to a DLL.

```cpp
  struct MemRegion {
    const uint64_t address;
    const uint64_t size;
  };

  enum Version {
    VERSION_US,
    VERSION_JP
  };

  const struct MemRegion SEGMENTS[2][2] = {
      {{1302528, 2836576},
       {14045184, 4897408}},
      {{1294336, 2406112},
       {13594624, 4897632}},
  };
  
  using Slot = array<vector<uint8_t>, 2>;
  class Game {
  private:
    Version m_version;
    HMODULE m_dll;
    const MemRegion* m_regions;

  public:
    Game(Version version, cstr dll_path) {
      m_version = version;
      m_dll = LoadLibraryA(dll_path);

      if (m_dll == NULL) {
        unsigned int lastError = GetLastError();
        cerr << "Last error is " << lastError << endl;
        exit(-2);
      }
      // this is a custom macro which calls a function in the dll
      call_void_fn(m_dll, "sm64_init");
      m_regions = SEGMENTS[version];
    }

    ~Game() {
      FreeLibrary(m_dll);
    }

    void advance() {
      call_void_fn(m_dll, "sm64_update");
    }

    Slot alloc_slot() {
      Slot buffers = {
        vector<uint8_t>(m_regions[0].size),
        vector<uint8_t>(m_regions[1].size)
      };
      return buffers;
    }

    void save_slot(Slot& slot) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        const MemRegion& region = m_regions[i];
        vector<uint8_t>& buffer = slot[i];
        cerr << "before memmove for savestate" << endl;
        memmove(buffer.data(), reinterpret_cast<void* const>(m_dll + region.address), region.size);
        cerr << "after memmove for savestate" << endl;
      }
    }
  };
```

When I call `save_slot()`, it should copy two blocks of memory to a couple of `vector<uint8_t>`s. This does not seem to be the case, though. The function finishes the first copy, but throws a segmentation fault at the second `memcpy`. Why does it only happen at the second copy, and how can I get around this sort of issue?

Edit 1: This is what GDB gives me when the program terminates:

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffac2164452 in msvcrt!memmove () from C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
```

Edit 2: I tried accessing the segments individually. It works, but for some reason, I can't access both segments in the same program.

Comment: What does the debugger say? Is `buffer` big enough? Is the result of `m_dll + region.address` in a readable section?

Comment: `buffer` is initialized to be big enough to hold the needed memory. In addition, this is a port, and the original Python version uses basically the same thing to access the data.

Comment: @ssbssa I've also tried increasing buffer size by 65536, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [link](https://drmemory.org/)

Comment: If you have gdb 10, `p $_siginfo` gives you detailed information of the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `HMODULE` is equivalent to `void*`. Since you can't really use pointer arithmetic on `void*`s, you have to cast it to a `uint8_t*` or equivalent to properly get an offset.

Here's what that looks like in practice:

```cpp
    void save_state(Slot& slot) {
      uint8_t* const _dll = (uint8_t*)((void*)m_dll);
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        MemRegion segment = m_regions[i];
        std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer = slot[i];
        memmove(&buffer[0], _dll + segment.address, segment.size);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The compiler should have caught this for you and given an error.  What is the definition of `HMODULE` in your environment?  It should be something like "pointer to incomplete type", on which pointer arithmetic is not possible and attempting `m_dll + region.address` would be a compile error.

Comment: I searched through MinGW-w64's files: `HMODULE` is typedef'd as `HANDLE` which is typedef'd as `PVOID`, which is finally typedef'd as `void*`. But there are multiple `DECLARE_HANDLE` macros, which may have screwed some things over.

Comment: Normally `STRICT` should be set and cause each of the various `HANDLE` types to be a typedef for a pointer to a forward-declared (therefore incomplete) structure.  At least that's how the official Microsoft headers so it.  But the mingw versions may take shortcuts...